# AsynchTask crashes on return from doInBackground

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public class TestSynch extends Activity {

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();


    new ProcessFileTask().execute(ctx);

    Intent i = new Intent(TestSynch.this, ListSchools.class);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.putExtra("arraylist", list);
    startActivity(i);

}

private class ProcessFileTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(Context... ctx) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> threadList = FileOperations.getListAsMaps(ctx[0]);
        return threadList;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {
         list = result;
        return;
    }
}
```

I can debug to the return threadList; line in doInBackground, and the ArrayList variable threadList is perfectly correct.

However, onPostExecute doesn't seem to get called and the Activity crashes on return from doInBackground, with LogCat suggesting a nullPointerException attempting to fire the Intent (which I have previously tested and worked ok before I started messing with AsynchTask)

Any idea why this is happening? The code seems simple enough...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Waqas is correct.  You are performing an `AsyncTask` that after it has executed sets a  `public static` variable `list`.  This list is used to pass into the `Intent` that you create in `onCreate`.  However there is no guarantee that the `AsyncTask` has actually completed at the point when you create the `Intent`.  As such the value of `list` at this point is `null`.

So, as Waqas suggests, you need to create the `Intent` *after* you have set a value for `list`, i.e. within `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking that nothing happened 'downstream' of the execute until it completed, but then it wouldn't be a thread, LOL

Comment: i think its better to keep it in a thread because you may not know how much time it may require to complete `FileOperations.getListAsMaps(ctx[0])`. And if it takes more than 5 seconds then your app qualifies for ANR and may be killed forcefully by Android

Answer (score 5):

You need to move **startActivity** part inside Async's **onPostExecute** method.

for example:

```
public class TestSynch extends Activity {

//public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();


    new ProcessFileTask().execute(ctx);
}

private class ProcessFileTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, 
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(Context... ctx) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> threadList = 
             FileOperations.getListAsMaps(ctx[0]);

        return threadList;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {
         Intent i = new Intent(TestSynch.this, ListSchools.class);
         i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         i.putExtra("arraylist", result);
         startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, AsyncTask executes asynchronously, as its name implies.  When you call 
     new ProcessFileTask().execute(ctx)

That piece of code goes off and does what it does but then the rest of your code continues to execute, which means that the list may not be populated by the time you try to start the new Intent because the AsyncTask might not have completed executing by the time you try to start the new Activity and pass in the List object to it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now - also I was confused by the debug process. By putting a breakpoint in the doInBackground method, my mind is concentrating on the AsynchTask whereas the main thread had already crashed by that point, but debugging wont show that up until it completes. Thanks for your comment